# Why is getReadableDatabase returning null?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm making a "choose your own ending" story using a SQLite database, however I've run into a bug where it's saying my database is null or something when trying to open the connection.
Could anyone enlighten me as to why this is happening?

Main Activity:

```
public class StoryActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            story = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("story");
        } else {
            story = new Story(this);
            story.getStory(1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
        state.putParcelable("story", story);
    }
}
```

Story Class:

```
public class Story implements Parcelable {
    private final String DATABASE_NAME = "story";
    private final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private int id, destinationA, destinationB;
    private String txtStory, decisionA, decisionB;
    private Cursor cursor;

    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private SQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper;
    private Context context;

    public Story(Context con) {
        id = -1;
        txtStory = "";
        decisionA = "";
        decisionB = "";
        destinationA = -1;
        destinationB = -1;

        cursor = null;
        db = null;
        dbHelper = null;

        bundleDB(con);
    }

    private void bundleDB(Context con) {
        try {
            String destPath = "/data/data/" + con.getPackageName() + "/databases/" + DATABASE_NAME;
            File f = new File(destPath);
            if (!f.exists()) {
                Log.d("TEST","Copying database");
                File directory = new File("/data/data/" + con.getPackageName() + "/databases");
                directory.mkdir();
                copyDB(con.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME), new FileOutputStream(destPath));
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("TEST", "FileNotFoundException: " + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("TEST", "IOException: " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    private void copyDB(InputStream i, OutputStream o) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        length = i.read(buffer);

        while (length > 0) {
            o.write(buffer, 0, length);
            length = i.read(buffer);
        }

        i.close();
        o.close();

        Log.d("TEST", "Database has been bundled with app");
    }

    public Boolean getStory(int i) {
        try {
            open();

            cursor = null;
            if (db == null) return false;
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tblStory WHERE id = ?", new String[]{Integer.toString(i)});
            if (cursor.getCount() == 0) return false;
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            id = cursor.getInt(0);
            txtStory = cursor.getString(1);
            decisionA = cursor.getString(2);
            decisionB = cursor.getString(3);
            destinationA = cursor.getInt(4);
            destinationB = cursor.getInt(5);

            close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("TEST", "getStory exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void open() {
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase(); // This is the line that is bugged
    }

    public void close() {
        db.close();
    }

    // Inner class for use via open() method
    private class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public DBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        }
    }

    // Parcelable methods
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    }

}
```

Database (located in assets folder):

```
tblStory (table)
    id (integer primary key)
    story (text)
    decisionA (text)
    decisionB (text)
    destinationA (numeric)
    destinationB (numeric)
```

LogCat:

```
Copying database
Database has been bundled with app
getStory exception: null
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace. What is the `Exception` thrown?

Comment: At the bottom of my original post you can see the LogCat for the first run.

Comment: That is the output of your `Log` calls. I mean the actual logcat output of the `Exception` being thrown.

Comment: What is the actual exception? You're printing out null as the result of `e.getMessage()`?

Comment: Sorry, how do I view the stack trace?

Comment: your oncreate method id dbhelper class is void!!

Comment: When I call `open()` it creates a new DBHelper and passes it the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may forgot to set the context in Story.

Just add

```
this.context = con;
```

in your Story's constructor.

Comment: Wow, I didn't think it would have been as simple a problem as that. Thanks a bunch!